# Що таке "спенцер"?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

Читаючи книгу "У неділю рано зілля копала" Ольги Кобилянської наткнувся на речення:

> Раду не відповів нічого, але замість того розірвав свій синій спенцер
>   на грудях і здіймив тут з шиї малий мішечок.

В СУМі не знайшов значення цього слова, а пошук в Гуглі також ні до чого не привів. Однак, в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf#page=368) (ст. 368) я знайшов слово "спенсер" (також там пише, що можливі варіанти "**спенцер**" та "шпенцер"), яке має значення "жіноча кофточка, коротка куртка", але ж у творі спенцер носить чоловік.

То чи є ці слова синонімами? А якщо ні, то що тоді означає слово "спенцер"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Спенцер – одяг на зразок жилетки.

[image]

Також [Spencer (clothing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_(clothing)).

> <sub>Пані та хлопець в коричневому носять спенцери.</sub>
>
> [image]